# Scrapy xpath removing text after < character

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, parsel

I am trying to get product information from [this](http://www.street311.com/belt-white) page. To get the description (present at the bottom of the page), I use the xpath

```
response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="description"]/table//text()').extract()[3].strip()
```

This gives me the description:

```
u'Color: White, Size:Free Size, With the body: Braided, Buckle: Automatic Deduction, With the body width: section ('
```

whereas the one present on the site is

```
Color: White, Size:Free Size, With the body: Braided, Buckle: Automatic Deduction, With the body width: section (<2cm), Belt Length: 93cm
Product Type: Belts, Accessories
```

I have verified that the content on the site loads even after disabling javascript. What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks like its cutting off because of the `<` sign, even BeautifulSoup cuts out the text after the `<`...very strange

Comment: this is a `parsel` bug, I'll check it on the repository [here](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/issues/23)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should still be handled without any *hack* but you could get this working with:

```
from parsel import Selector
...

s = Selector(text=response.body_as_unicode(), type='xml')
s.xpath('//*[@itemprop="description"]/table//text()').extract()[3].strip()
# gives u'Color: White, Size:Free Size, With the body: Braided, Buckle: Automatic Deduction, With the body width: section (2cm), Belt Length: 93cm'
```

the problem here is that `parsel` (inner `scrapy` parser) uses `lxml.etree.HtmlParser(recover=True, encoding='utf8')` which removes this kind of weird characters to avoid problems.